# want to copy table from database of default instance to another instance database in sql server 2012 using RODBC

Tags: r, sql-server-2012, rodbc, dsn

I am able to fetch the table of default instance database. All I need to do is just copy that fetch data to save in named instance database using this RODBC, Any help can appreciate. Advance Thanks.

```
> library("RODBC")
> odbcChannel <- odbcConnect("SasDatabase")
> odbcClose(odbcChannel)
> odbcChannel <- odbcConnect("SasDatabase")
> sqlFetch(odbcChannel, "PR0__LOG1")
```

Fetched Data

```
[     DateTime            Temp1 Temp2 PK_identity
1   2018-08-27 09:59:00    51   151           1
2   2018-08-27 10:00:00    11    11           2
3   2018-08-27 10:01:00    71    71           3
4   2018-08-27 10:02:00    31   131           4
```

Closing Conn

```
odbcClose(odbcChannel)
```

Want to copy this fetched data in another instance database.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not really clear, but it sounds like you want to upload the fetched data to a second database. If so then use `RODBC` or similar (depends on database type) to connect to the second database then you can use DBI function to upload. Some examples would be :

```
DBI::dbAppendTable()
```

or

```
DBI::dbSendQuery()
```

Any answer will need more detail about the second database instance to be more specific.

An excellent resource for R and databases is https://db.rstudio.com/